# android home key Response Process

Tags: android

There are some question about android HOME key on android4.2 !

- add Log at KeyEvent.java$getKeyCode()
- adb logcat & press the home key

output keyCode = `122` !
but the HOME keyCode is 3
and the MOVE_HOME keycode is `122`
so,I can't use the home key !

compareed the files under /frameworks/base/data/keyboards/ with a normal,it is the same!

- How the home key working?
- How many times about the key mappings?(from Linux kernel -- driver -- frameworks)
- How the maps relation(Linux kernel -- driver -- frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone

This problem has been solve!

The two volume key and power key are difference with BACK HOME MENU key!

Volume ,Power key use the default keyboard layout **Generic.kl** .

However,the BACK HOME and MENU key use  **ft5x06_ts.kl** which send frome Linux kernel

solution:

modify the makefile

**LOCAL_MODULE :=ft5x06_ts.kl**